# double integral.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I just received this problems from a friend, and I think its a HW problem.

its:

$$
\int_1^e \int_{1+y^2}^5 \cos (x- \ln x) \ dx \ dy
$$

I looked at it, and If I did graph the the region right then the point where y=e intersects with is beyond where where   x=5 intersects with $$ \ x=1+y^2 $$
so looks like the integral should be

$$
\int_1^2 \int_{1+y^2}^5 \cos (x- \ln x) \ dx \ dy
$$

I rewrote the integral as:
 $$
\int_1^5 \int_1^{\sqrt {x-1}} \cos (x- \ln x) \ dy \ dx
$$

is my reordering the region good?, and is there any suggestion on how to compute this integral?.

Comment: I get an expression in terms of *x* and [incomplete $\Gamma$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) of imaginary arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right except that the lower limit of the outer integral should be $2$ and not $1$. That is:

$$I = \int_2^5 \int_1^{\sqrt{x-1}} \cos(x - \ln x) \, dy \, dx$$